# How can I unit test an HTTP service in Ballerina?

Tags: testing, service, ballerina

Suppose I have an echo HTTP service written in Ballerina as follows:

```
import ballerina/http;

service / on new http:Listener(9090) {

    resource function post echo(@http:Payload json payload) returns json {
        return payload;
    }
}
```

How can I write unit test the behavior of the `echo` resource method?

Comment: This is explained in Ballerina documentation: [Testing services and clients](https://ballerina.io/learn/testing-ballerina-code/testing-services-and-clients/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer can be found from the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation. It contains what I was looking for. However, should quoting/pointing to the documentation be the answer rather than closing the question?

Comment: @user272735 Can you add your comment as an answer with some quoting so that I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write unit tests for an HTTP service using the Ballerina HTTP client.

Place the tests inside the `tests` directory inside your Ballerina project.

Following is an example test:

```
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/test;

@test:Config {}
function testService() returns error? {
    http:Client httpClient = check new("http://localhost:9090");
    json requestPayload = {message: "hello"};
    http:Request request = new;
    request.setPayload(requestPayload);
    json responsePayload = check httpClient->post("/echo", request);
    test:assertEquals(responsePayload, requestPayload);
}
```

Here, we send a payload and get it back using an HTTP client, and then check whether the echo service sends back the same payload.

When running the tests, the service will be started automatically. You don't have to run them manually.